# APEX_UTIL.GET_SINCE off by 6 minutes

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How can it be that APEX_UTIL.GET_SINCE with the current time tells me that that timestamp is 6 minutes in the future? Before it worked as expected and returned 'now' but since a short while it is saying that the current date is in the future.

The System time of the underlying Linux System has the correct time (up to a milisecond) and the sysdate returned by that statement is also the correct current time, so I expect that Oracle function to use a wrong reference from somewhere else?

[image]

Comment: Good catch. Reproduced in 18.2 and 19.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it doesn't

> tell that timestamp is 6 minutes in the future

but *in the past.*

---

It looks as if the first call sets a "mark", and subsequent calls return how much time has passed since that.

The first call is at 19:39:11 and it is "now":

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:39:11 Now
```

I'm now just pressing the UP key on the keyboard and hitting the ENTER:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:39:12 1 seconds from now

SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:39:13 2 seconds from now

SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:39:14 3 seconds from now

SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:39:15 4 seconds from now

SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:39:16 5 seconds from now

SQL>
```

After typing the above message (I mean, answering the question), I'm calling it again; it says that it's been 3 minutes since the mark:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:41:41 3 minutes from now

SQL>
```

In order to reset it, I'm exiting SQL*Plus and starting over:

```
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pet Lis 18 19:42:31 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> col result format a50
```

New mark set to 19:42:36:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:42:36 Now

SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:42:38 2 seconds from now

SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') sysd, apex_util.get_since(sysdate) result from dual;

SYSD     RESULT
-------- --------------------------------------------------
19:42:39 3 seconds from now

SQL>
```

Comment: Nice answer. The cache exists for consistency, say when rendering a report with many rows that uses #SINCE# on SYSDATE. Without the cache, it would be possible for some of the results to be inconsistent. In the context of APEX, this works fine as connections are only checked out of the pool for a brief period before package state is reset. With SQL Developer, the reset doesn't occur since it uses a dedicated connection.

Comment: Very interesting observation and great explanation.  Question becomes, is this a bug or intended functionality?

Comment: I was really hoping for an answer that involved quantum computing and causality violation. :-(

Comment: That is an interesting answer that opens a new question: I am not using this function in Apex. I am using it in a Rest Webservice. And from my understanding every time that Rest Service is called, a new connection should be created meaning the "Mark" should be reset. But If I do a Rest call now with the code in my question I still get an answert that is off (although it varies between 0 and 4 minutes)

Comment: Huh, it seems that you guys expect something I simply don't know, sorry.  Anyway, Dominik, what problem are we actually trying to solve here? What do you use that function for? Perhaps there's an alternative.  Besides, you said that "since a short while" it doesn't work as it used to. What changed?